# File is being made but FileConfiguration is not putting text in it

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I'm trying to make a Bukkit/Spigot plugin which stores user data with YML files, and I can't make a list in file that gets created when the users joins. I'm using the built in parser.

The Code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {

    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    File f;
    f = new File(getDataFolder(), "UserData/" + p.getUniqueId() + ".yml");
    if (!f.exists()) {

        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileConfiguration mapconfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File(getDataFolder() + "UserData/" + p.getUniqueId() + ".yml"));
        mapconfig.createSection("Mobs");
        mapconfig.set("Mobs", "mob1");
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("[Morph] Creating new user file " + p.getUniqueId() + "for user " + p.getName());
    }

}
```

The files are created, but they are empty.

```
Mobs:
    - mob1
```

I need the section empty. What am I doing wrong?

Updated code--------------------

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {

    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    File f;
    f = new File(getDataFolder(), "UserData/" + p.getUniqueId() + ".yml");
    if (!f.exists()) {

        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileConfiguration mapconfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File(getDataFolder() + "UserData/" + p.getUniqueId() + ".yml"));
        mapconfig.createSection("Mobs");
        List<String> ListOfStrings = Arrays.asList("mob1");
        mapconfig.set("Mobs", ListOfStrings);
        try {
            mapconfig.save(getDataFolder() + "UserData/" + p.getUniqueId() + ".yml");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("[Morph] Creating new user file " + p.getUniqueId() + "for user " + p.getName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the edited YAML configuration to the player's file by using `mapconfig.save(file)` in a try block after you've added all the nodes etc.

If you'd like the list "Mobs" to be initially empty, leave out the `mapconfig.set("Mobs", "mob1");` line.

To add elements to the "Mobs" list, you'll need to create a list of strings to add. As far as I can tell, each time you want to update the list by removing or adding another string, you need to first load the YAML file (extra step after creating the configuration) using `mapconfig.load(file)`, then get the current values (strings) in the list using `mapconfig.getStringList("Mobs")`, update the list as you like, re-set it to the "Mobs" node and save the file again (example below).

```
//Initial strings when file does not exist
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList("mob1", "foo", "bar");
mapconfig.set("Mobs", listOfStrings);
//Save config to file (in try block)
```

And to update the list if the file already exists, for example by adding a new string.

```
//After creating the file configuration
//Load file (in try block)
List<String> stringList = mapconfig.getStringList("Mobs");
stringList.add("mob4");
mapconfig.set("Mobs", stringList);
//Save config to file (in try block)
```

In case something still doesn't work, here is my slightly cleaned up version of your code that worked for me.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    File file = new File(getDataFolder() + "/UserData/" + player.getUniqueId() + ".yml"); //Assuming all required directories exist
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("[Morph] Creating new user file " + player.getUniqueId() + "for user " + player.getName());
        FileConfiguration fileConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
        fileConfig.createSection("Mobs");
        List<String> ListOfStrings = Arrays.asList("mob1", "mob2", "mob3");
        fileConfig.set("Mobs", ListOfStrings);
        try {
            fileConfig.save(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the topic with the code I have now. It still doesn't work, it just creates the file, with nothing in it, not even the start of the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you remove the file between runs, that code only runs when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep, removed it everytime before testing

Comment: When saving the file, pass the reference of the file (f) you instantiated earlier to the method instead of creating a new file object (even though it's technically the same file). This fixed the bug for me: `mapconfig.save(f)`. I believe there's also no good reason why you should create a new file object for every method call.